# How to get a variable to have 2 decimals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, comparison, decimal

I have a variable i would like to force to have 2 and always 2 decimals. Im comparing to a currency. Often i get a comparison looking like the following.

```
if self.price != price
  #do something
end
```

Where `self.price = 120.00` and `price = 120.0`. The `self.price` is set with a `:precision => 2` in the model, but how do i do the same with a variable, cause this seems to fail in comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Numeric
def round_to( decimals=0 )
  factor = 10.0**decimals
  (self*factor).round / factor
  end
end


if self.price.round_to(2) != price.round_to(2)
  #do something
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use integers for storing currency, for example, use store 100 cents for 1 dollar. It reduces headaches and may improve performance if it matters.